# Need help to understand why COM is missing in "Reference Manager"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, com

I don't have much experience with COMs.

I have a project that references 2 COMs `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` and `AXISMEDIACONTROLLib`
[image]

When I manually delete `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` I cannot add it back from "Reference Manager" since it's not shown there. The only COM that's there is `AXISMEDIACONTROLLib`.
[image]

Can someone help to understand or give a direction to how `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` was added at first place if it's not shown in "Reference Manager"?

Comment: `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` was most likely registered and the other wasn't: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jigarme/2008/04/28/how-to-register-net-assembly-for-com-interop/

Comment: I believe that list shows registered components. You can always just use the browse button to manually find and add your DLL.

Comment: The strange thing is when I delete the reference and then revert the change (I'm using SVN), the deleted `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` reference is shown in project but not in `Reference Manager`. I can successfully build the project. When I right click on the reference and check the path it's `...\obj\Release\AxInterop.AXISMEDIACONTROLLib.dll`. When I delete the `obj` folder it's recreated again. So, it does has reference, but I cannot find to where.

Comment: So, if you're saying it's not registered, how `AxInterop.AXISMEDIACONTROLLib.dll` get's into `..ojb\Release` folder then. Please help me to understand.

Comment: It sounds like the `obj\Release` folder has been checked in to SVN.

Comment: @JuanR, it's not. I can even delete it and it will be created with  AxInterop.AXISMEDIACONTROLLib.dll when I build the project

Comment: I see. Perhaps there is a build event to create the Interop wrapper?

Comment: When I installed AXIS from https://www.axis.com/en-us, it create `AXIS Communications` in `Program Files (x86)` with sample project. I've uploaded it to here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VqsP4iHO-ID3g44LkXcRJVAewmz4XUkA/view?usp=sharing. They also reference `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` but it's not shown in `Reference Manager` and I didn't find anything in build events. Can I ask you to take a look at the samples project and see if you figure it out?

Comment: It is an ActiveX control (note the ax prefix).  Not just a library but also a control that you can drop on a form.  Right-click the toolbox > Choose Items > COM components tab.

Comment: @HansPassant, you're right! I also found this link https://softelvdm.com/Documentation/SftTree%20OCX%207%205/Topic/g_toolboxvs.
Can you write your comment as an answer so I'll mark it as accepted to give you credit?

Comment: You know a lot more about this product than I do, just share what you discovered in your own post and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a COM reference, .NET will create an Interop wrapper for you. The interop types can be embedded into the target assembly, or they can be put in their own assembly (AxInterop.AXISMEDIACONTROLLib.dll).

If you select the assembly reference `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` in the Solution Explorer window and press `F4` to see the properties, you will most likely see the `Embed Interop Types` property is set to `False`. This causes the `Copy Local` property to become editable and the Interop assembly to be generated on compilation.

Comment: But I cannot find any AxInterop.AXISMEDIACONTROLLib.dll anywhere. Not even in the installation folder that can be downloaded here https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VqsP4iHO-ID3g44LkXcRJVAewmz4XUkA.

Comment: So, I don't understand how it's added as reference at first place

Comment: @theateist: It is not added. It is **made** for you by the compilation process. Cool nickname by the way... :-)

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I open the samples project and go to `Project->References` I can see there are `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib, AXISMEDIACONTROLLib, System, System.Data,...` references. `System, System.Data` I know how do add, but how did they add `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` reference?

Comment: @theateist: My educated guess is that the reference was added after compilation, then checked in. If you look at the source of your project file with a text editor, you will find it there. Try this: Download the project in a new working folder. Open it, but do not compile the code yet. Look at the references. The Interop one will probably have a yellow triangle icon on it. Once you compile the project, the triangle will disappear. I believe you don't need the reference. Delete it and compile the project. It should work fine. If it gives you errors, then correct the references manually.

Comment: The sample code that comes with `AXIS` didn't have yellow trinagle. I do need the reference since objects from `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib` are used. E.g. `AxAXISMEDIACONTROLLib.AxAxisMediaControl`.